# How to compute gradient of the product of a scalar and vector function?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

I'm trying to figure out how to compute the gradient of the following expression.

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R},\; g:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$,
$$
\nabla (f(x)\cdot g(x)) = \; ? \;\;\;  \mathrm{for}\, x\in\mathbb{R}^n
$$

Does a compact notation for the result exist in general, without having to multiply everything out and computing partial derivatives element by element ?

Thank you!

Edit:

Apologies for any confusion. I've learned everything in a different language so a bunch of English terminology is still unclear to me. When using a $\nabla$ symbol, what I meant to signify is that the resulting object is a matrix. I'm deriving second order terms in a Lagrangian that is composed of a bunch of scalar and vector valued functions. I got the first order terms correct, producing a gradient, but differentiating the gradient is what brought me to ask this question. In the book I am reading, the Hessian is represented as $\nabla^2 \mathcal{L}$, which I assume I can derive by applying the gradient operator to the gradient vector itself, giving me a Hessian matrix as a result?

Comment: Hi, welcome to MSE. If $f$ takes scalar values and $g$ vectors, then $f\cdot g$ takes vector values, then what's the meaning of it's gradient?

Comment: Do you mean the divergence of $f(x)\cdot g(x)$?

Comment: Apologies for any confusion. I've updated my original question to clarify

Comment: If you're using matix notation, you need to decide whether $\nabla$ is a row or column vector. If it's a column vector, then the Hessian of a scalar valued $\mathcal L$ is $\nabla\nabla^{\mathrm T}\mathcal L$, where $\mathrm T$ denotes the transpose, and your expression $\nabla(fg)$ is non-sensical and should maybe be $\nabla^{\mathrm T}(fg)$, which is the divergence of $fg$. If $\nabla$ is a row vector, then instead we would need $\nabla^{\mathrm T}\nabla\mathcal L$, and $\nabla(fg)$ is the divergence of $fg$.

Comment: Thank you @NicholasTodoroff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you mean the *divergence* of $f(x)g(x)$, then yes we can compute this. The derivative of any expression is the sum of the derivatives of its parts; we can represent this as
$$
  \nabla\cdot(f(x)g(x)) = \dot\nabla\cdot(f(\dot x)g(x)) + \dot\nabla\cdot(f(x)g(\dot x)).
$$
The dots indicate what is being differentiated; the undotted $x$ should be thought of as constant for the purpose of diffentiation. Since $f$ is a scalar, we rearrange to get
$$
  \nabla\cdot(f(x)g(x)) = (\nabla f(x))\cdot g(x) + f(x)\nabla\cdot g(x),
$$
where now $\nabla$ differentiates directly to its right as usual.

---

With $\nabla$ interpreted as a row vector, and elements of $\mathbb R^n$ as column vectors, we can write the same thing in matrix notation simply as:
$$
  \nabla(f(x)g(x)) = (\nabla f(x))g(x) + f(x)\nabla g(x).
$$

Comment: Since the OP refers to the Hessian matrix, which is not a scalar nor vector, you should consider the tensor product $\vec\nabla\otimes(f\vec g)$, or equivalently $\vec\nabla(f\vec g^T)$ (where all vectors are column matrices).

Comment: @mr_e_man You're right, that is also another possibility, though since $f$ is a scalar we still get the same sort of product rule by the same reasoning $$\nabla(fg^T) = (\nabla f)g^T + f\nabla g^T.$$